# Coloring Cells of Data Tables with legend below Extracting it to excel

Tags: r, rscript

I want to color some of the cells of datatable and then create some kind of legend below. This is my code

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,10,11,11,11,12,1,2,2,3,4,4,55,5,0,6,0,9)
y<-c(30,303,303,30,50,50,5,50,5,55,50,5,50,5,50,66,7,6,6,6,6,6,66,6,77,8,88)
Data<-cbind(x,y)
Data<-datatable(Data,caption = 'Data')%>%
formatStyle('y',
          backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(0,50),c( 'normal','normal','yellow')))
save_html(Data,file="Data.html")
```

I want to add a memo or legend below which will explain what the color yellow means and extracting it as excel file

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be extracting it to Excel anyway, why not just extract it once you've colored your cells and then add it manually?

One of my favorite college professors gave me some great advice once when I was first learning R. I was trying to drop columns from a long dataset (30+ columns) and had asked him what the easiest way to do it in R would be. He asked me if I knew how to do it in Excel, which of course I did, and he said "There's a lot of ways to solve a problem, but the best way is the way that YOU can solve it."

It wouldn't hurt to know how to do it in R, but this is something that I don't think would be easier to do there than in Excel (or necessary, outside of edge cases).